# How to include .cpp and .hpp files of a library in my c++ project in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

Apologies for a very basic question. I am trying to port from a CMake project into a visual studio project.
Basically I want to run the project from visual studio without using the CMake file. In the project I need to port, there are many folders and sub folders that contains many .cpp and .h files. These are included to the main cpp file as using `#includes`.

**My Case**

The library I want to include
[image: Glimpse of the library Libpfs]

and my main.cpp

[image: My Main.cpp]
For instance to make things simple assume I have a main file  main.cpp and this file includes `#include "Libpfs/colorspace/colorspace.h"`. The Libpfs is a folder and it has many sub folders one of which is colorspace folder and this has many .h and  .cpp files. One .h file is colorspace.h that is included in main.cpp using the `#include` and the folder also has .cpp file i.e. **colorspace.cpp**.

**My Attempt**

My objective is include them to my project.
Now here is what I have tried
in Visual Studio **Project**->**properties**->**C/C++** in **Additional Include Directories** I gave the path of the folder that contains **Libpfs** but this approach did not work and gave linker errors this might be because I have no lib files for the **Libpfs** (correct me if I am wrong). I only have .cpp files of the corresponding .h files. I presume the cause of error is the the .cpp files are not compiled yet.

**My Question**

How can I include the cpp file to my project as well (not the lib files since I dont have those).

Comment: You shouldn't typically include cpp files of a library, but link to the compiled .so .lib .dll or so. If you set an include path use `#include <bar/foo.h>`. P.s. a good library would have a seperaat "include" directory with only headers..

Comment: Just add the cpp files to the project and they'll get compiled and linked

Comment: Thanks @JHBonarius. But what if I dont have the .lib or .so or .dll?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Does this mean I would need to add every .cpp file of the 3rd party library to the project?

Comment: Often a library comes with a manual on how to compile it. If it doesn't,  is it a library you are using or just an additional module? Visual studio can create library projects, so you could compile it yourself.

Comment: @JHBonarius I have added images so that you can also see what I am trying to include is a separate library or a module

Comment: Have you tried 'right click on project in solution explorer/Add/Existing Item...' to add all the cpp files and h files to your project? That's the normal thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this](https://github.com/LuminanceHDR/LuminanceHDR/tree/master/src/Libpfs/colorspace) for a source, I find the `CMakeLists.txt` to contain nothing special.

```
FILE(GLOB COLORSPACE_H *.h)
FILE(GLOB COLORSPACE_HXX *.hxx)
FILE(GLOB COLORSPACE_CPP *.cpp)

SET(LIBPFS_H ${LIBPFS_H} ${COLORSPACE_H} ${COLORSPACE_HXX} PARENT_SCOPE)
SET(LIBPFS_CPP ${LIBPFS_CPP} ${COLORSPACE_CPP} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

So you can just add all the files to a VS C++ project. I would use some directory management, to separate these sources from your own.

But anyhow, in that case, you should include the sources by relative path. E.g.

```cpp
#include "../../Libpfs/colorspace/colorspace.h"
```

Alternatively, you could put everything in a separate C++ library (static `.lib` or dynamic `.dll`). In that case you should but the binaries in in a `bin` path and add that as additional library directory (project properties of your own project) and put all the header files in an `include/Libpfs` path and add that as additional include directory. In that case you should include the files as.

```cpp
#include <Libpfs/colorspace/colorspace.h>
```

## On another topic

```cpp
#define pow_F(a,b) (xexpf(b*xlogf(a)))
```

I found this define only [in the sources of the same source used above](https://github.com/LuminanceHDR/LuminanceHDR/blob/master/src/TonemappingOperators/pattanaik00/tmo_pattanaik00.cpp).
It seems to be sourced from [sleef](https://github.com/gwiazdorrr/sleef/blob/master/purec/sleefsp.c) and according to [this](https://github.com/LuminanceHDR/LuminanceHDR/issues/144) it should give a speedup. But you should measure if that is really still true, instead of doing copy-paste/[cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) programming.
I think generally you should use the standard library [`std::pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow), which has overloads for `float`, `double` and `long double`. The compiler will in most cases optimize its use for you.

Comment: Yes the source is right. Adding sources by relative path would require each and every cpp file to be changed to relative path. Which I dont want to. The alternative option can be opted but the problem is there is no .lib or .dll available for the project.

Comment: will adding the path of .h files in the additional include directory and by loading all the cpp files to sources of visual studio project work?

Comment: "there is no .lib or .dll available for the project." <-- [then make your own](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-160). Second question: probably yes. But probably also need to change paths.

Answer (score 0):

open explorer , look for  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDK\`  and then go after dir with alot of `.lib`'s in its \lib .
it's an msvc source for  `.lib` and other stuff like that . copy your library there